# jQuery slider on dynamic content, using bind() not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, I am trying to add a row to a table on click and in the  of this dynamically generated row I want a jQuery UI slider. The row appears but the slider is not added to the div...

I have just noticed that when I click the area the slider appears, I assume this has to do with the bind click event, how can I bind it to appear with no click in the table cell area?

```
$('.add_task').unbind().bind('click', function(){

    $('.add_cancel_wrap').html('<button class="cancel_add_task btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>');

    $('.cancel_add_task').unbind().bind('click', function(){
        window.location = window.location.href;
    });

    var user_id = $(this).data('user-id');

    var $html = $('<td></td><td><input class="description" type="text" value="" placeholder="Description" /></td><td><div class="time-slide"></div><div id="slide-range-area"></div></td><td></td><td><a href="" class="save_new_task" title="Save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></a></td><td><input class="time" /></td>');

    $html.bind('click', function(){

        $(function() {
            $(".time-slide").slider({
                range: false,
                min: 0,
                max: 480,
                step: 10,
                slide: function(e, ui) {
                    var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
                    var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

                    if(hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
                    if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

                    $('#slide-range-area').html(hours+' Hrs '+minutes+' mins');
                }

            });
        });

    });

    $('<tr></tr>').appendTo('#tasks_table').hide().append($html).fadeIn('slow');

});
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have the click handler... you can initialize the plugin once the dom element is created so

```
$('.add_cancel_wrap').on('click', '.cancel_add_task', function () {
    window.location = window.location.href;
});

$('.add_task').unbind().bind('click', function () {
    $('.add_cancel_wrap').html('<button class="cancel_add_task btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>');

    var user_id = $(this).data('user-id');

    var $html = $('<tr><td></td><td><input class="description" type="text" value="" placeholder="Description" /></td><td><div class="time-slide"></div><div class="slide-range-area"></div></td><td></td><td><a href="" class="save_new_task" title="Save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></a></td><td><input class="time" /></td></tr>');

    $html.find(".time-slide").slider({
        range: false,
        min: 0,
        max: 480,
        step: 10,
        slide: function (e, ui) {
            var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
            var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

            if (hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
            if (minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

            $html.find('.slide-range-area').html(hours + ' Hrs ' + minutes + ' mins');
        }

    });
    $html.hide().appendTo('#tasks_table').append().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

also there are minor changes related to delegated event handlers for `add_cancel_wrap`